# Running UI5 on Node JS server

Tags: node.js, sapui5

I'm trying to run my ui5 pages on Node.js server. What I've done till now is created a UI5 project with a simple index.html file calling my other ui5 views showing a text message. When I run it without node js it runs fine and shows me the message.

What I'm trying to achieve now is run this on top of my node server. So I've configured a server.js file for my node and it starts up fine. In there I'm calling up my above index.html file. it calls it fine but it gives an error inside it saying sap is undefined meaning it is not able to find my ui5 resources like sap-ui-core.js and thus the error. I'm not sure why it is not able to find it.

I've created the ui5 project using eclipse which provides me the ui5 resources under the below directory but even if I try to put the resources directory under the web content directory it is not able to find it.

[image]

After manually putting resources directory:

[image]

Below is how my index.html looks like:

[image]

Has it got something to do with the resource root that I define or please if you can suggest how can I get it working.

Awaiting your responses eagerly.

Thanks,
AW

Adding to cschuff response:

Hello, thanks for taking time to help me out. Yes my apps namespace is different and definitely not something with sap.ui. Though I've got a way around of getting it to work but still would like to get this to work as well as it is much cleaner. The way I've got it working now is by creating a seperate node project altogether and then gradually adding my UI5 pieces to it and by gods grace it is running fine now. But I'm not sure why the same concept if I apply on a UI5 project created in eclipse, it gives me sap is undefined error.

[image]

Comment: Hello All, I see when I try to run the index.html outside node js it is trying to look for the other js files within the sap ui directory for which it fails to load them giving access denied error but not sure why. So why it is not able to run on the node js server??

Comment: What does the network tab say from where it tries to load sap-ui-core.js?

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion that you misconfigured node.js server. Try start from scratch:

```
mkdir app
cd app
npm install -g express-generator
express -f
npm install
node .\bin\www
```

Than put all of your files of your project and `resource` in `public` directory. And try to open `http://localhost:3000/index.html`

Comment: The way I've set up my environment is created a UI5 project in eclipse with a simple index.html showing some text. And then defined package.json without any dependencies. I've then installed express in it with node install --save express, defined my server.js & started the server. The server starts up fine. Individually the pieces works fine like my server starts fine, previewing my ui5 index which calls the UI5 components and shows the text works fine but when I try to call the same index.html on node server it does not gets the resources. Not sure why. Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The /resources are delivered by the com.sap.ui5.resource.ResourceServlet (see your web.xml; web.xml and Servlets are used in the Java World e.g. by Java Application Servers or Servlet Containers like Tomcat)

The ResourceServlet listens on the url-pattern /resources/* meaning every time a request is send to an url matching this pattern the ResourceServlet (a Java class) will step in, look up the right .jar file and return the required JavaScript file from it. This won't work with a plain web server like Apache.

I don't know much about express but I guess it is not able to run Java Servlets and thus is not able to deliver your SAPUI5 resources the same way Tomcat does.

To work around this you still have some options:

1. Use Express to serve your application sources and load UI5 from Tomcat while developing. This might lead to cross-origin problems (since localhost:8080 and localhost:3000 are considered different origins)

   <script src="http://locahost:8080/resources/sap-ui-core.js" ...
2. Unpack all the UI5 .jars you need and place them in YourApplication/resources/.

[image]

BR
Chris

Comment: Hi, I've already tried putting in the resources folder with the js files unpacked from the jar files under the webcontent directory as shown above in my screen shot. Even then it does not finds it when I refer the scripts inside it with script tag path like src="resources/sap-ui-core.js".

Comment: you should definitely NOT use sap.ui as a namespace for your app! Could you post a screenshot from what is IN your /resources? Furthermore a look into network tab of your dev tools should give you a hint where it try to load the resources from. Post that too

Comment: It's most probably you resourceRoot. Try using a different namespace like my.app. Sorry for not properly reading your question ;)